# how to do somthing before an HTTP POST request in node.js?

Tags: python, node.js, express

I'm very new to nodejs what I try to do is upload an image with some data to nodejs API but before saving data to Mongo DB I try to do some process to this uploaded image using Python class then I will save the results to DB

so can I send uploaded image to python code and waite the result before saving any data to DB

my code is here

```
  router.post('/img2text', upload.single('photo'), (req, res) => {
    // Create the object for insertion into database
    const Img2text = new img2text({
      imgPath: req.file.path,
      sender: req.body.sender,
      processed: 0,
      resultText: "no result",
    });
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////start
    var exec = require("child_process").exec;
    exec(`python uploads/hello.py ${req.file.path}`,(error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        Img2text.processed=0;
        Img2text.resultText='no result'
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
      }
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      Img2text.processed=1;
      Img2text.resultText=stdout.toString('utf8');
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      console.log(req.query.firstname);
    });
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////end

    // Save  into database
    Img2text.save((err) => {
      // Check if error
      if (err) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: err });
      } else {
        console.log("img saved !!")
        res.json({ success: true, message:img.resultText }); // Return success message
      }
    });
  });
```

> if the python code takes so long time my object will be empty?

---

any answer will be greatly appreciated

---

Comment: Your Mongo code has to wait before the python code is complete?
Is that your requirement. If so, try 'callbacks','promises' or 'async functions'

Comment: thanks, @wahid_abdul yes that exactly what I want to do, how can I use  'callbacks','promises' or 'async functions' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use `Promise`,If not refer this link [Promise MDN](https://s.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Just wrap your process in a `Promise` and when you finish with your process resolve it and save it to database.

```
router.post('/img2text', upload.single('photo'), (req, res) => {
        // Receive your image

        let pythonProcess = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
         // do your process
         reolve() // resolve with updated data
        })
        pythonProcess.then(img =>{
         //save to db
        })
   })
```

Now In Your case best possible, I prefer is to use `aync/await` [Async/await MDN](https://javascript.info/async-await). Do not take it as another way to do it, It is just modern way to use `promise`. As internally `await` also setup `promise` chain. You have both options, either you can go it through `promises` you will get handy to the one of the best thing of `javascript`  or If you want small piece of code go with `await`.

```
router.post('/img2text', upload.single('photo'), async(req, res) => { // To use await function need to be a async function
    // Create the object for insertion into database
    const Img2text = new img2text({
      imgPath: req.file.path,
      sender: req.body.sender,
      processed: 0,
      resultText: "no result",
    });
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////start
    var exec = require("child_process").exec;
    await exec(`python uploads/hello.py ${req.file.path}`,(error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
        Img2text.processed=0;
        Img2text.resultText='no result'
        console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
        return;
      }
      console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
      Img2text.processed=1;
      Img2text.resultText=stdout.toString('utf8');
      console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      console.log(req.query.firstname);
    });
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////end

    // Save  into database
    Img2text.save((err) => {
      // Check if error
      if (err) {
        res.json({ success: false, message: err });
      } else {
        console.log("img saved !!")
        res.json({ success: true, message:img.resultText }); // Return success message
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: happy to help :)